# Написание 3 слов в одной ячейке таблицы

Tags: html

как сделать на хтмл вот так 3 слова (либо либо и ) в одной ячейке таблицы [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сделайте в 3 ячейках, только с нулевыми border

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно Вас интересует: объединение ячеек (одна ячейка на 3 колонки) или скрытие границ между тремя ячейками?

Answer (score 2):

Для создания таких колонок и объединения, нужно использовать аттрибуты `rowspan, colspan` в правильном назначении, а также тег `tbody`.

```css
table tr td{
  text-align:center;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td{
  border:0;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
  border-left:1px solid #000;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) td:last-child{
  border-right:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
     Тип ЧС 
    </td>
    <td colspan="3">
      Критерии
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      Силы и средства привлекаемые для ликвидации ЧС
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       либо
     </td>
     <td>
       либо
     </td>
     <td>
       и
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       Количество пострадавших N, человек
     </td>
     <td>
       Материальный ущерб G на день возникновение ЧС, руб.
     </td>
     <td>
       Зона ЧС
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>
         Локальная
       </td>
       <td>
         N <= 10
       </td>
       <td>
         G <= 100 т. р.
       </td>
       <td>
         Не выходит за пределы территории объекта
       </td>
       <td>
         Организации
       </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```